# Laravel implement user friends (chat) presence

Tags: laravel, broadcastreceiver, real-time, laravel-echo, social-network-friendship

I’m having some trouble understanding how to inplement presence channels in a real-time laravel application.

From what i’ve read in the documentation and a lot of other online resources about this, i only need to broadcast on a Presence channel and have clients listen on that particular channel. By the way, I'm using laravel 5.6 and on the front end I use Larvel Echo.

So, my problem is that channel name I need to broadcast to. If it’s something generic like “*chat*”, **ALL** the users in my application will broadcast to this channel and users who have no ideea who that user is (not a friend) receive this notification and they have to process this new information. Ofcourse I can choose not to update the UI or just do nothing if the user is not in their friends list but this just seems like a lot of useless procesaing of notifications on the client side. Doesn’t seem like a good ideea in my opinion.

Second option would be to broadcast presence to a unique channel name like “*chat-[unique]*” where “*[unique]*” would be something like the logged user’s id/hash but this just means that every client that loggs in the application has to listen for ALL friends notifications, so he has to connect to *chat-5426*, *chat-9482*, *chat-4847* and so on, for all his friends. Again, this does not seem efficient. But that’s not all. The friends list is paginated so a user, after is logged in, only sees his first 20 friends (unless he scrolls down) and I have no limit on how many friend a user can have - I can implement a limit but still, it would be in the thousands so I don’t think I can get all the users from the DB in one query. I had the ideea of using this last method, to listen to each user's channel on the front end just as they are, paginated. Then, when scrolling and navigation arround, if a new user is visible in the viewport, add it to my friends object (no UI change) and start listening  on his presence channel. I can see this method failing pretty easy though.

However I think about this, it always seems like online presence is verry resource consuming and almost not worth it for a small startup, I don't know. I have no ideea what a good way would be to implement it as I`ve never done it before. I would greatly appreciate any help with this because all online resources I've found on the subject implement the first method I asked about, all users connectiong to a generic channel but this always works in tutorials because they only have like 2-3 users in the DB and none mantion a user having friends. I can't see this working in the real world, but I may be wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting to show if a user is online or if they're included in a specific chat?

Comment: If they are online, without starting a conversation with them. Basicaly, for the end user, it's just to show the green circle next to the user name

Comment: In that case I don't think a presence channel is the right thing. A presence channel would be used more for when a user is on a specific chat or viewing a specific webpage. For your situation, I would suggest having something like a "userLoggedIn" event that simply changes the status of that user to show they're logged in (and then maybe one for a logged out user).

Comment: Ok, thought some time about what you said. and you might be right. But I don't feel I'm solving any issues with the UserLoggedIn/LoggedOut event. How do I push the LoggedIn event form a user to another ? To receive that notification, a user has to listen for ALL hist friend's LoggedIn/LeggedOut events, and this on the front end. We`re back to my second option from the original question.

Comment: I'm starting to think more and more that you're right about the presence channel not being the right thing. Maybe broadcasting the online presence is the wrong ideea and I should focus on a different solution, maybe polling the server every 10 seconds or so for online friends or long polling (not likely though)